# jQuery Ajax setTimeout being random

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that lets me get data from ajax.php and display it in a div. It is supposed to display information for 3 seconds and then hide the #ajax-content and display #welcome-content

However, although most of the time it works and seems to be 3 seconds, occasionally it would randomly be much shorter. A few times it did not even feel like 1 second.

Have I done something wrong? or is there a way to fix this?

```
$('#user_id').on('change', function() {
$('#user_id').focus();
id = $("#user_id").val();
$.post("ajax.php", { username:id } ,function(data){
    $("#welcome-content").hide();
    $("#ajax-content").show();
    $("#ajax-content").html(data);
        setTimeout(
           function(){
            $("#ajax-content").hide();
            $("#welcome-content").show();
           },
           3000
        );
});
```

Comment: Should work as expected...

Comment: This is the normal setTimeout behavior. Javascript does not use concurrent threads. Check out [link](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use a simple way to code this ?

```
$('#user_id').on('change', function() {
    $('#user_id').focus();
    id = $("#user_id").val();
    $.post("ajax.php", { username:id } ,function(data){
        $("#welcome-content").hide();
        $("#ajax-content").show();
        $("#ajax-content").html(data);
        setTimeout(HideAjax_ShowWelcome, 3000);
    });
});



function HideAjax_ShowWelcome () {
    $("#ajax-content").hide();
    $("#welcome-content").show();
}
```

The setTimeout statement only asks for the name of the function, it is not a call, do not put parentheses.
If you put in this place a function (a pointer in fact) and its code, the javascript engine must make each time an evaluation of this code [because it is for him just text], which explains the response time random ...

This being the best is to test this version of writing then to tell us if it is better so?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in following snippet, it executes in perfect time + ~2-5 ms.

You can fit in few timing logs to check what is executing at what time; that might help you understand it better.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const logs = $('#logs');
  const log = data => `<li>${data}</li>`;

  $('#send').on('click', function() {
    logs.html('');
    logs.append(log('Starting: ' + (+new Date)));
    $.post("//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
      username: 5
    }, function(data) {
      const x = +new Date;
      logs.append(log('Received: ' + x));
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          const y = +new Date
          logs.append(log('Hiding: ' + y));
          logs.append(log('Diff: ' + (y - x)));
        },
        3000
      );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="send">Send AJAX</button>
<ul id="logs"></ul>
```